# docker compose with build --pull option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build

What is the equivalent of **docker build --pull .** in a docker-compose?

The docker compose reference only indicates build context, build file, and build args, but I can't find syntax to specify build options inside a docker compose.

Answer (score 5):

It's the same `docker-compose build --pull`:

```
$ docker-compose build --help
Build or rebuild services.

Services are built once and then tagged as `project_service`,
e.g. `composetest_db`. If you change a service's `Dockerfile` or the
contents of its build directory, you can run `docker-compose build` to rebuild it.

Usage: build [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    --force-rm  Always remove intermediate containers.
    --no-cache  Do not use cache when building the image.
    --pull      Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
```